# What are some "must-read" papers for someone getting into Quantum Cryptography?

Tags: quantum-cryptography, quantum-computing

I'm a graduate student that just finished a first course on quantum computation. I've also done a graduate-level course in (classical) cryptography.

I'm interested in Quantum Cryptography and would like to know what people would consider the most important papers for me to read if I want to get an intro to QC, for someone of my background. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, these kinds of questions are off-topic. Welcome to [chat] to discuss your future.